# how to download server side file javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, onclick, filewriter

We developing web sit.we have two textFiles in server `http://192.168.3.134:8080/Helphands/forTest1.txt`  and `http://192.168.3.134:8080/Helphands/forTest2.txt`  .We need is When we button click we need download `forTest1.txt` file and then count 1 write to `forTest2.txt`  Please guide me . We are new this

We download like this

```
  </script>
        <a href="http://192.168.3.134:8080/Helphands/forTest1.txt" download>
  aaaa
</a>
```

now we need count number of download that as to be sent to forTest2.txt

Comment: the question is not very clear, could you please rephrase it?

Comment: Do you have any code you have tried? Have you done a Google search?

Comment: @SimoneRiboldi we have two textFiles in server .forTest1 and forTest2.txt .We need is when we click on download button we need download forTest1 and count will be pass to forTest2 Please give me any idea

Comment: @PavanAlapati do you mean something like page/download hit counter?

Comment: @sitilge yes we need to count number of hits

Comment: @sitilge yes but it's not web page it's text File

Comment: Any one guide me Please : How do I count downloads from my website 
We can download file .We need count of download

Answer (score 0):

you may want to create a javascript function on the onclick event of the link that allow the user to download the file and at the same time, update the counter on the second file.
Below a simple counter of click on a link

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var clicks = 0;
function linkClick() {
    document.getElementById('clicked').value = ++clicks;
}

document.write('<a href="#" onclick="linkClick()">Click Me!</a>');
```

Then you just have to save that variable on the file (using a server side language)

Comment: yes exact .we need exact as you said Please guide me.We need download file .now we need update counter on the second file